# How do I remove switches from this 4-way setup to make it 1-pole?

Tags: switch

We have an old Intermatic timer for our front lights that appears to be wired to two three-way switches. Both of the extra switches are within 10 feet of the primary switch and are much more trouble than they are worth.

I’d like to remove the two extra three way switches so that I can replace the old timer with a modern single pole smart switch.

The wiring of the timer looks like this:
[image]

The west 3 way is wired like this:
[image]

And the east 3 way is wired like this:
[image]

How would I go about removing the east and west switches?

Thanks!

Here are some additional photos of the timer and from its instruction manual:
[image]

[image]

[image]

East box
[image]

West box
[image]

Comment: To clarify, you have   1 light on 3 switches (*a three way switch is  used for 1 light on 2 switches- a 4 way switch is for 1 light on 3 switches*) You want to eliminate 2 switches so that it is a 1 light, 1 switch set up. Correct?

Comment: Just changed the title to clarify.

Comment: A clear picture of the labeling on the back of the switch in the first picture may help.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve added some pictures.

Comment: @RA can you post photos looking into the backs of the 2nd and 3rd boxes please?

Comment: Photos of inside of boxes added.

Comment: Can you get us shots that more clearly focus on the backs of the boxes involved?